# Symfony ElasticaBundle listener and query_builder_method

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

I need upload in elastic, when I created entity Lead, only who have status approved, this is my, mapping:

```
                 persistence:
                      driver: orm
                      model: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Lead
                      provider:
                        query_builder_method: createIsActiveQueryBuilder
                      listener: ~
                      finder: ~
```

and my query_builder_method: createIsActiveQueryBuilder:

```
public function createIsActiveQueryBuilder()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Lead', 'd')
        ->where('d.statusLead = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', 'approved')
    ;

    return $qb;
}
```

When I run I have upload lead only status approved

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset
```

created Lead

```
    $lead = new Lead();
    //some logic
    $manager->persist($lead);
    $manager->flush();
```

But when I create new Lead with default status 'not_approved' this lead uploaded in elastic, why I not understand listener upload this lead, why not work query_builder ?

Answer (score 0):

I add to elastic config indexable_callback and create in entity class function isPublished and when I created new Lead with status not_approved this lead not upload in elastic. And very good this - when I change status 'approved' - lead uploaded in elastic, then I change status for not_approved and lead deleted in elastic. This is WIN

```
    public function isPublished()
{

    if ($this->getStatusLead() === self::STATE_TO_BE_INDEXED_IN_ELA) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

        lead:
        finder: ~
        types:
            lead:
                 indexable_callback: 'isPublished'
                 mappings:
                      id:
                          type: integer
                     persistence:
                      driver: orm
                      model: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Lead
                      provider:
                        query_builder_method: createIsActiveQueryBuilder
                      listener: ~
                      finder: ~
```